# What is a batch file command to open a cmd window?

Tags: cmd, dos

Yes, I tried googling this, by the way.

Basically, what is the dos command that will open a dos command window?

In other words, if you have a .bat file full of script commands, what command can you do that will open a command window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this maybe. In the command line it starts it so I assume in a bat file it'll do the same.

```
start cmd
```

If you want it to run another bat or something you can do:

```
start script.bat
```

If you want it to close then:

```
start cmd /c script.bat
```